# Why is my custom control not receiving focus on its own?

Tags: delphi, focus, vcl, tcustomcontrol

I am working on a custom control, inherited from a `TCustomControl`. I am overriding a few events such as `KeyDown` so that I can capture keyboard and mouse input. However, for whatever reason it is not automatically getting focus on its own when user clicks it. I have to add `SetFocus` in the `MouseDown` event, and only then does it actually receive focus. But I'm pretty sure I shouldn't have to do that. Why is this happening, and how do I fix it so that it will get focus on its own without manually calling `SetFocus`?

- Custom control's `TabStop` is set to `True`.
- Control's parent form (and all forms) have `KeyPreview` set to `False`.

I am defining these methods like so:

```
type
  TMyControl = class(TCustomControl)
  ...
  protected
    procedure KeyDown(var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState); override;
    procedure KeyUp(var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState); override;
    procedure KeyPress(var Key: Char); override;
    procedure MouseDown(Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState;
      X, Y: Integer); override;
    procedure MouseMove(Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer); override;
    procedure MouseUp(Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState;
      X, Y: Integer); override;
    ...
  end;
```

And then the implementation:

```
procedure TMyControl.KeyDown(var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  inherited;
  ...
  Invalidate;
end;

procedure TMyControl.KeyPress(var Key: Char);
begin
  inherited;
  ...
  Invalidate;
end;

procedure TMyControl.KeyUp(var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  inherited;
  ...
  Invalidate;
end;

procedure TMyControl.MouseDown(Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Integer);
begin
  inherited;
  SetFocus; //<-- This shouldn't be necessary...?
  ...
  Invalidate;
end;

procedure TMyControl.MouseMove(Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  inherited;
  ...
  Invalidate;
end;

procedure TMyControl.MouseUp(Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Integer);
begin
  inherited;
  ...
  Invalidate;
end;
```

Comment: Yes, it is necessary. Clicking doesn't automatically set focus to the control. You need your function call.

Comment: Existing things where you click and it doesn't set the focus to the clicked control: dragging files, taskbar buttons, screen keyboard...

Comment: Interesting. I've written custom controls in the past, and don't remember having to do this. Anyway, I guess that's my answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that manually calling `SetFocus` on your control's `MouseDown` handler is exactly what's required. After all, some controls get a "click" event outside of actual click scenarios, and thus shouldn't automatically get focus. And so, if you want to grab focus from the mouse, you must do so exclusively upon a mouse click.

Furthermore, regarding the `TabStop` property, it only defines whether it gets focus upon the user `tabbing` between controls. `TabOrder` is directly related, defining in what order it gets focus upon tabs.

Perhaps the custom controls you've made in the past were inherited from a specific control which already had this functionality built-in?